# How to use Azure Function App Function Tester (Example)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Could someone provide and example of how to use the Azure Function App Function Tester with an Example?

This is some default sample code for a webhook function:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Webhook was triggered!");

    string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

    if (data.first == null || data.last == null)
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
        {
            error = "Please pass first/last properties in the input object"
        });
    }

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
    {
        greeting = $"Hello {data.first} {data.last}!"
    });
}
```

[This is an image of the Function App Function Tester in MS Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1g33.png)

Answer (score 1):

In the Tester blade, you could set the HTTP method, header, parameter,etc.

For the sample code you gave, you should provide Request body like a **JSON** format, then click the **Run** button.

```
{
    "first": "Azure",
    "last": "Functions"
}
```

[image]

Then you could find the function log.

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to use different http methods,

1. you could go to **Integrate** of the function, then check the **Selected HTTP methods** option.
2. you could set the methods in the `function.json` file.

For example:

`"methods": [
        "get",
        "post",
        "delete",
        "head"
      ]`

Comment: Could you show how to use the different http methods? Meaning some examples using request body, maybe some diff code to support it (if necessary).

Comment: @TJ972 I have updated my answer, you could refer to it.